# JavaFX: How to make the underlaying Node accessable?

Tags: java, layout, javafx

I have a `Pane` and a `VBox` inside of a `StackPane`. I added the `Pane` first and the `VBox` on top of it. The `VBox` includes several kes that in turn have `Button`s as children. I use the normal `Pane` as a "canvas" to position `Line`s on it. The `Line`s as well as the `Button`s need to be interactive. So by clicking on them they shall for example change their color.
But at the moment the `Pane` and its `Line` objects are shown but they are covered by the `VBox` so I can not interact with them but only with the `Button`s.

How can I provide that I can interact with the `Line` as well, though they are in a lower layer of the `StackPane`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`pickOnBoundsProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#pickOnBoundsProperty) of your container `Node`s (`VBox` and `HBox`) to `false`.

> Defines how the picking computation is done for this node when
>   triggered by a MouseEvent or a contains function call. If pickOnBounds
>   is true, then picking is computed by intersecting with the bounds of
>   this node, else picking is computed by intersecting with the geometric
>   shape of this node.

As result, "transparent" areas of the `HBox` and the `VBox` will not register the click event.

**Example:**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

            Pane pane = new Pane();
            pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red;");
            StackPane sp = new StackPane();
            VBox vbox = new VBox();

            HBox hbox = new HBox();
            hbox.setSpacing(30);


            for (int i = 0; i< 5; i++) {
                Button b = new Button("Button");
                b.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Button clicked"));
                hbox.getChildren().add(b);
            }

            vbox.getChildren().add(hbox);
            sp.getChildren().addAll(pane, vbox);

            Line line = new Line(10, 10, 500, 10);
            line.setStrokeWidth(3);
            pane.getChildren().add(line);
            line.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                System.out.println("Line Clicked!");
            });

            // Set pickOnBounds to vbox and hbox
            vbox.setPickOnBounds(false);
            hbox.setPickOnBounds(false);
            root.setCenter(sp);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Solved my problem! Very convenient and easy that way.

Answer (score 1):

They are covered cause the VBOX is in front of the Pane.

> First Way:

You can `setVisible(false)` the VBox so the Pane can be accessible and then `setVisible(true)` the VBox again.

> Second Way:

You can use  methods called `toBack();` and `toFront();` and bring a `Node` back or front to the hierarchy:

```
vBox.toBack(); //the the vBox goes back to the hierarchy,it is like zOrder in html
```

and then use:

```
 vBox.toFront(); //to bring the vBox again in front.
```

**Finally:**

You can somewhere provide a `ToggleButton` that when is pressed the `VBox` is appearing and when is not pressed the `VBox` is disappeared.